# how to change the value a pointer within a struct points to in c?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, segmentation-fault

After trying to test the following function, i have determined the line commented out gives a seg fault when i try to run the program:

```
uint8_t ll_push_front(struct List *list, int value){
        if (list == NULL)
                return 1;
        struct ListEntry *node = (struct ListEntry *) malloc (sizeof(struct ListEntry));
        if (node == NULL) exit (1);
        if (list->head_ == NULL || list->tail_ == NULL || list->size_ == 0) {
                list->head_ = node;
                list->tail_ = node;
                node->prev_ = NULL;
                node->next_ = NULL;
    // =====>>  *(node_->val_) = value;
                ++(list->size_);
                return 0;
        }
        list->head_->prev_ = node;
        node->next_ = list->head_;
        node->prev_ = NULL;
        *(node->val_) = value;
        list->head_ = node;
        ++(list->size_);
        return 0;
}
```

what is wrong with doing `*(node_->val_) = value` and how should it be properly declared?

here are the structs:

```
struct ListEntry {
    struct ListEntry * next_;  // The next item in the linked list
    struct ListEntry * prev_;  // The next item in the linked list
    int * val_;                // The value for this entry
};

/* Lists consist of a chain of list entries linked between head and tail */
struct List {
    struct ListEntry * head_;  // Pointer to the front/head of the list
    struct ListEntry * tail_;  // Pointer to the end/tail of the list
    unsigned size_;            // The size of the list
};
```

This is how i initilize the list:

```
void ll_init(struct List **list) {
        *list = (struct List *) malloc (sizeof(struct List));
        if (list == NULL) exit (1);
        (*list)->head_ = 0;
        (*list)->tail_ = 0;
        (*list)->size_ = 0;
}
```

Comment: How is `node_` declared and where is it set?

Comment: Need to know how you have defined the structures

Comment: If val_ is an int, then you should do `node_->val_ = value;`

Comment: Your `val_` member is an `int` pointer (`int *`). Did you allocate it some memory? The code I see doesn't. And in fact, it seems to be using whatever value happens to be in that pointer after your node-level `malloc()`. This is called an *indeterminate* pointer, and usage of it for eval or assignment is **undefined behavior**. Finally, I fail to see why it is a pointer in the first place. it would seem a regular `int` should suffice.

Comment: If you use a pointer to val then you must check this pointer before an assignment, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have decided to use an pointer to an integer you need to `malloc` that as well.

i.e.

```
struct ListEntry *node =  malloc (sizeof(struct ListEntry));
```

Then

```
node->val_  = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

This will make

```
*(node->val_) = value
```

Work

Alternatively use

```
struct ListEntry {
    struct ListEntry * next_;  // The next item in the linked list
    struct ListEntry * prev_;  // The next item in the linked list
    int val_;                // The value for this entry (no pointer)
};
```

Then

```
node->val_ = value
```

Will work

Answer (score 1):

You can use `memcpy(node_->val_, &value)`, but what's your purpose, why not declare `node_->val_` to `int`